Не появляется рамка для обрезания фото
Использую бибилиотеку cropperjs.
Файлик index.html выглядит следующим образом:
<div class="container">
<div>
    <img class="pic" src="./picture.jpg" id="image">
</div>

В JS-файле я получаю картинку при помощи getElementById, после чего передаю её в конструктор класса и добавляю aspectRatio:
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';

const image = document.getElementById('image');
console.log('image=',image)
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
    aspectRatio: 0,
});

Однако после этого рамка для обрезания картинки на картинку не добавляется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему? Что сделать, чтобы она добавилась?

На странице cropperjs, в приведённом примере aspectRatio представлен в другом виде, да оно и логично, — это же соотношение сторон, но, если вас оно устраивает, то тогда ищите другие параметры коих куда больше.
